# Skip tracing of the subendpoint in Spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer-tracing, spring-boot-3

We are using tracing Spring boot 3, there was external get call we want to skip from tracing because it had some sensitive information. Tried `ObservationPredicate` with `ServerRequestObservationContext` but no luck.  Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

For the sub url's we have to use `ClientRequestObservationContext`.

```java
    @Bean
    ObservationPredicate ignoreUrl() {
        return (s, context) -> {
            if (context instanceof ClientRequestObservationContext clientRequestObservationContext) {
                return !clientRequestObservationContext.getCarrier().getURI().contains("/ignore");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```